# python csv file add to field based off another field

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file looks like this:

[image: CSV File]

I have a column called “Inventory”, within that column I pulled data from another source and it put it in a dictionary format as you see.

What I need to do is iterate through the 1000+ lines, if it sees the keywords: comforter, sheets and pillow exist than write “bedding”  to the “Location” column for that row, else write “home-fashions” if the if statement is not true.

I have been able to just get it to the if statement to tell me if it goes into bedding or “home-fashions” I just do not know how I tell it to write the corresponding results to the “Location” field for that line.

In my script, im printing just to see my results but in the end I just want to write to the same CSV file.

```
from csv import DictReader
with open('test.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for line in csv_dict_reader:
        if 'comforter' in line['Inventory'] and 'sheets' in line['Inventory'] and 'pillow' in line['Inventory']:
            print('Bedding')
            print(line['Inventory'])
        else:
            print('home-fashions')
            print(line['Inventory'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last column of your csv contains commas. You cannot read it using DictReader.

```
import re

data = []
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    # Get the header row
    header = next(f).strip().split(',')
    for line in f:
        # Parse 4 columns
        row = re.findall('([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)', line)[0]
        # Create a dictionary of one row
        item = {header[0]: row[0], header[1]: row[1], header[2]: row[2],
                header[3]: row[3]}
        # Add each row to the list
        data.append(item)
```

After preparing your data, you can check with your conditions.

```
for item in data:
    if all([x in item['Inventory'] for x in ['comforter',  'sheets', 'pillow']]):
        item['Location'] = 'Bedding'
    else:
        item['Location'] = 'home-fashions'
```

Write output to a file.

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, data[0].keys())
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: They are actually tags. does that make a difference?

Comment: I meant commas.  Since your file is a csv file and you have commas in the value, you cannot read it with DictReader. It will interpret commas inside your columns as a separate column.

Comment: ok.. unfortunately i'm having a hard time understanding it so even though i'm sure it will work great. I'm not sure what to do with it..

Comment: I commented the code. The line with a regular expression just parse the line to obtain four columns. If you have a question, let me know.

Comment: ok, I am begining to understand, I just added some prints to see what it was doing..here and there. is your code suppose to update the csv file? or just print  to screen. that is the only piece it is not doing. I was going to attach a screenshot of what I see. but not sure how to attach a screenshot on secondary conversations like these?

Comment: and I guess one other question would be. in your dict creation for 'item'  you  create a key:value pair of header to row. What happens when I do not know the actual amount of row it will be? i know it will be a large amount though..

Comment: You have to write to a file. You may open another file or overwrite the old file.  It would be better if you write to another file. Your file may have many rows. The code will loop through all rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218735/discussion-between-randal-and-pramote-kuacharoen).

Comment: it works like a charm. i even added more fields on to my CSV and just updated the row and item variable accordingly. thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

`csv.DictReader` returns a dict, so just assign the new value to the column:

```
if 'comforter' in line['Inventory'] and ...:
    line['Location'] = 'Bedding'
else:
    line['Location'] = 'home-fashions'
print(line['Inventory'])
```

Comment: Yes and no. You can't append to a line in the original file without overwriting the subsequent line. You can, however, write to a different workfile, then replace the original file with it when you're done.